# Regular expression: if, else if, else

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse FSM statements of the Gezel language (http://rijndael.ece.vt.edu/gezel2/) using Python and regular expressions

```
regex_cond = re.compile(r'.+((else\tif|else|if)).+')  
line2 = '@s0 else if (insreg==1) then (initx,PING,notend) -> sinitx;'
match = regex_cond.match(line2);
```

I have problems to distinguish *if* and *else if*. The *else if* in the example is recognized as a *if*.

Comment: Isn't \t a tab? So it's actually searching for else<tab>if instead of else<space>if? I would try switching to else\sif.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this; use [`pyparsing`](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) instead. You'll thank yourself later.

---

The problem is that `.+` is greedy, so it's eating up the `else`... do `.+?` instead. Or rather, don't, because you're using `pyparsing` now.

```
regex_cond = re.compile( r'.+?(else\sif|else|if).+?' )
...
# else if
```

Answer (score 3):

a \t matches a tab character. It doesn't look like you have a tab character between "else" and "if" in line2. You might try \s instead, which matches any whitespace character.

Comment: I might also suggest that you could remove the double parentheses ((...)) and replace with one set (...), as one set will provide both a capture and an alternate.

Comment: True, but not the only problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate problem is that `.+` is greedy and so it matches `@s0 else` instead of just `@s0`. To make it non-greedy, use `.+?` instead:

```
import re

regex_cond = re.compile(r'.+?(else\s+if|else|if).+')  
line2 = '@s0 else if (insreg==1) then (initx,PING,notend) -> sinitx;'
match = regex_cond.match(line2)
print(match.groups())
# ('else if',)
```

However, like others have suggested, using a parser like [Pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) is a better method than using `re` here.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if im wrong, but RE are not good for parsing, since its only sufficient for Type2 languages. For exaple you can't decide weather or not ((())())) is a valid statement without "counting", which regex can't do. Or, to talk about your example, if else else could not be found as invalid. Maybe im mixiung up scanner/parser, in this case please tell me.

Comment: Parsing nested structures with Regex was pretty well shot down in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). This question related to HTML but applies equally well to any nested structures